# how can I create an array with random numbers?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axQUE.png)what I want is to create an array with random numbers so I can then add them to another array with a foreach

```
let jsonlength = this.accesoriosJson.length
let a = 0;
let randomNumber = new Array()
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
  a++
  if (a > jsonlength) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }else{
     randomNumber.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10))
  }
},100)

console.log(randomNumber) 

randomNumber.forEach(valor => {console.log(valor)})
```

I don't understand why the foreach doesn't work because console.log(randomNumber) works just fine

Comment: Why do you use a delay to push the nunbers? (where you wait 100 ms)

Comment: Are you sure `console.log(randomNumber)` works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your purpose you should do something like this.

Call `getRandomArray()` after `clearInterval(myInterval)` to get `RandomArray`.

```js
let jsonlength = 6;
let a = 0;
let randomNumber = new Array()
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  a++
  if (a > jsonlength) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    getRandomArray();
  } else {
    randomNumber.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10))
  }
}, 0);

function getRandomArray() {
  console.log(randomNumber);

  randomNumber.forEach(valor => {
    console.log(valor)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When the `forEach` call happens, `randomNumber` doesn't have any entries in it, so `forEach` doesn't do anything. You're only adding entries **later**, when the `setInterval` callback runs. That happens long after (in computer terms) your `forEach` call.